# Adding a title to showDatePicker in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have looked everywhere for a way to add some text to the modal that appears when showDatePicker is fired, but haven't had any luck. I don't want to replace the text that says the date, but add text above it. Does anyone know how to do this? [this is the modal that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZh9b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want with the public api for the DatePicker.

I would suggest copying the code of DatePicker into your project and editing it to achieve what you want.

from the line: 139

```
    return Container(
      padding: padding,
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          yearButton,
          dayButton,
          Text('your text'),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

the result:

[image: the result]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this question relates to the title shown at the top of the DatePicker dialog. I have a program where it is confusing to show simply "Select date" which appears to be the default. On loading my program, it immediately shows the two datepickers for start date and end date, so without a title showing which date, it is confusing.

According to the documentation (which may be a subsequent change since the posting), the heading of the datepicker dialog can be changed at follows:

The following optional string parameters allow you to override the default text used for various parts of the dialog:

helpText, label displayed at the top of the dialog.

It would be nice if this could be centered, but it appears to solve the problem that I had. viz:

```
DateTime? dtmSelected = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: dtmDefault,
        firstDate: _dtmMin!,
        lastDate: _dtmMax!,
        helpText: sHed);
```